# Send each row an Excel Spreadsheet as an individual email in Outlook

Tags: excel

I need a piece of code I can use to create a Macro that outputs each row of my spreadsheet below as an individual Outlook email, to the email address in the column titled "Email" below. I also need to add the columns titled, "Call", "Type", "Balance" and "Company Name" to the the body of the email.
I also need to add some free text to my email which is the same for each email sent: ***Body of email***

[image: example]

Comment: What did you try so far to achieve this? And what is the concrete problem?

Comment: Hi have tried using the Flow add on in Excel but it keeps falling over. I have also tired using some VBA code from the web that might work in a macro but I am not a code writer, which is why I was asking for help 

Comment: I am trying to automate a process that otherwise is very manual too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following procedure should accomplish this task. It is assumed that your data is stored in the columns `A:G`. If this is not the case, you will need to modify the specific parts accordingly. In addition, the code already includes the feature that the subject-varying part of the "body of the e-mail" is already in bold face.

Importantly, in its current state, the code only creates and displays the e-mails. If you want to send them, you need to change this part of the code from `.Display` to `.Send` (see comment in the code):

```
Sub sendOlMail()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ws As Worksheet, olApp, olMail As Object, cell As Range, lr As Long, i As Integer, strBody1, strBody2 As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row 'determine row with last value for loop

    strBody1 = "Dear Sir/Madam,<br/><br/>" _
                & "We are still awaiting payment from you for: <br/><br/>"

    strBody2 = "Please can you provide us with an update? We have recently resent out invoice/card payment links as a gentle reminder. <br/><br/>" _
    & "Please note it is a legal requirement for anyone using wireless radio equipment to hold a valid licence. On occasions we carry out site visits to ensure that any frequencies being used for wireless radio equipment are being used legally. <br/><br/>" _
    & "Unfortunately, we may also have to look at revoking your company’s access to our Online Portal until such time as this payment is made. <br/><br/>" _
    & "Kind Regards, Joe Bloggs"

    For i = 2 To lr
        Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)
        With olMail
            .To = Range("G" & i).Value
            .Subject = "E-Mail Subject" 'adjust subject of your e-mail
            .htmlBody = strBody1 & "<b>" _
                        & Range("A" & i).Value & ", " & Range("C" & i).Value & ", " & Range("D" & i).Value & ", " & Range("E" & i).Value & "</b>" & "<br/><br/>" _
                        & strBody2
            .Display 'change to .Send if you want to send out the e-mail
        End With
        Set olMail = Nothing
    Next i
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

**EDIT:** Adding additional functionality to the code based on comment

1: I have modified the `.htmlBody` element so that it also contains the headers of the respective categories. Instead of hard-coding the names of the headers, I take the headers directly from the Excel file (first row in the respective columns). The advantage of this specification is that it is dyanmically specified, which means that if you change the name of your heading in the Excel file, it will be automatically reflected.

---

2: Including the signature is a bit more tricky, but there are several ways to accomplish this. For this step, you should make sure that you specify your signature outside the loop, otherwise this will cause unnecessary overhead. You should also make sure that you declare your signature as a string variable.

(I) Retrieving the signature from the Outlook folder. This is a bit more complicated, but for me the better solution since the formatting of the signature is preserved (I have included this approach in the updated code).

(II) Retrieving the signature from the body of an email. The disadvantage of this method is that the formatting specified by the user is not preserved. However, if this is not an issue, this could be an even simpler solution. Then simply change the signature-related parts of the code with the following parts:

```
Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)
olMail.Display
signature = olMail.Body
Set olMail = Nothing
```

---

The code with the additional functionalities (i.e., inclusion of headers and signature) looks as follows:

```
Sub sendOlMail()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ws As Worksheet, olApp, olMail As Object, cell As Range, lr As Long, i As Integer, strBody1, strBody2, signature As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row 'determine row with last value for loop

    ' prepare signature
    signature = Environ("appdata") & "\Microsoft\Signatures\"
    If Dir(signature, vbDirectory) <> vbNullString Then signature = signature & Dir$(signature & "*.htm") Else signature = ""
    signature = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFile(signature).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2).ReadAll
    
    strBody1 = "Dear Sir/Madam,<br/><br/>" _
                & "We are still awaiting payment from you for: <br/><br/>"

    strBody2 = "Please can you provide us with an update? We have recently resent out invoice/card payment links as a gentle reminder. <br/><br/>" _
    & "Please note it is a legal requirement for anyone using wireless radio equipment to hold a valid licence. On occasions we carry out site visits to ensure that any frequencies being used for wireless radio equipment are being used legally. <br/><br/>" _
    & "Unfortunately, we may also have to look at revoking your company’s access to our Online Portal until such time as this payment is made. <br/><br/>" _
    & "Kind Regards, Joe Bloggs"

    For i = 2 To lr
        Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)
        With olMail
            .To = Range("G" & i).Value
            .Subject = "E-Mail Subject" 'adjust subject of your e-mail
            .htmlBody = strBody1 & "<b>" _
                        & Range("A" & 1).Value & ": " & Range("A" & i).Value & ", " _
                        & Range("C" & 1).Value & ": " & Range("C" & i).Value & ", " _
                        & Range("D" & 1).Value & ": " & Range("D" & i).Value & ", " _
                        & Range("E" & 1).Value & ": " & Range("E" & i).Value & "</b>" & "<br/><br/>" _
                        & strBody2 & "<br/><br/>" _
                        & signature
            .Display 'change to .Send if you want to send out the e-mail
        End With
        Set olMail = Nothing
    Next i
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Karl thank you so much, it works a treat, you have no idea how much I appreciate this :)

Comment: @BrendanRamsey Great to hear that the answer is useful. You can consider to mark the answer as accepted for others to know that you no longer need help. For this, click on the check mark beside the answer (left) to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. When it turns green it means you accepted that answer.

Comment: Thanks Karl, I will do. I know you have provided the code to add the data in the columns titled, "Call", "Type", "Balance" and "Company Name" to the the body of the email. But is it possible we can amend the code so that the email shows not only the data in each of those rows, but the column header associated with them please? So for example, Call: 603581, Type: Annual License, Balance: 56, Company Name: Fred Simpson. Also how can I add my auto signature to the email instead of "Kind Regards, Joe Bloggs", please?

Comment: Do I need to start a new post for the question directly above guys? 

Comment: @BrendanRamsey I will try to edit my post in the evening to incorporate these features, which should be relatively simple!

Comment: Thanks so much Karl that would be amazing 

Comment: Thanks Karl, I have now marked the query as solved. You have been very kind and supportive and I really appreciate it. Thank you :)