# Generate an email with a range from a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I've a command button on Excel to set up an email.

I want to send a range from the worksheet. I would like it to keep the formatting if possible.

I believe the issue is with:

```
xMailBody = ThisWorkbook.Activeworksheet("Sheet1").Range("AA65:AE67")
```

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 
    
    'Updated by 2022/09/16 
    
    Dim xOutApp As Object 
    Dim xOutMail As Object 
    Dim xMailBody As String 
    
    On Error Resume Next 
    
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0) 
    
    xMailBody = ThisWorkbook.Activeworksheet("Sheet1").Range("AA65:AE67") 
    
    On Error Resume Next 
    
    With xOutMail
        .To = Range("AD69")
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = "" 
        .Subject = Range("AD70") 
        .Body = xMailBody
        .Display   'or use .Send 
    End With 
    
    On Error GoTo 0 
    
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: See my response here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73005935/send-each-row-an-excel-spreadsheet-as-an-individual-email-in-outlook/73008522#73008522

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send each row an Excel Spreadsheet as an individual email in Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73005935/send-each-row-an-excel-spreadsheet-as-an-individual-email-in-outlook)

Comment: Use Ron de Bruin's [RangetoHtml](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Paste Excel range in Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18663127/paste-excel-range-in-outlook)

Comment: Hi karl, something like this.  Thank you

Comment: Hi niton, not sure why but nothing shows up from the range.  I filled my sheet from D4 to D12.  Thank you

Comment: I think I underestimated this endeavor but will continue to plug away at it.  I was thinking it was going to be a simple line addition like adding an attachment but it's not.  Thank you everyone for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

You have xMailBody declared as a string then are stating that it is the desired range.

Try DIMing it as a range!

Comment: How does it help to set up the message body?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I've noticed that you are trying to set the `Body` property which is a plain text string:

```
.Body = xMailBody
```

If you need to preserve formatting you can create a well-formed HTML formatting and then assign it to the `HTMLBody` prperty of Outlook items.

The Outlook object model supports three main ways of customizing the message body:

1. The [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-body-property-outlook) property returns or sets a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
2. The [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-htmlbody-property-outlook) property of the MailItem class returns or sets a string representing the HTML body of the specified item. Setting the `HTMLBody` property will always update the Body property immediately. For example:

```
     Sub CreateHTMLMail() 
       'Creates a new e-mail item and modifies its properties. 
       Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem 
       'Create e-mail item 
       Set objMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
       With objMail 
        'Set body format to HTML 
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML 
        .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>Enter the message <a href="http://google.com">text</a> here. </BODY></HTML>" 
        .Display 
       End With 
     End Sub
```

3. The Word object model can be used for dealing with message bodies. In that case you can just copy the required range in Excel and then paste to the message directly using the [Paste](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.paste) method from the Word object model. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx) for more information.

Also you may consider using the [RangetoHTML](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm) function to convert Excel data to the HTML markup.