# Creating an email using a range of text from Worksheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to generate an email using a macro that I don't have to copy and paste the resulting data in the body of the email and attach the file. The worksheet pulls data from other worksheets and I use Excel functions to generate the syntax. So far the code I've used will only generate the email, subject line, and attachment but no body text. I am unable to show a photo or show the code.

Comment: When you say no body text is generated, what do you mean by that ? From where will this text be obtained ?

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73005935/send-each-row-an-excel-spreadsheet-as-an-individual-email-in-outlook/73008522#73008522) for a related question.

Comment: The text is in the worksheet itself. The issue is getting the code to automatically generate an email window with the worksheet text in the body of the email.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Send_Mail()

Dim OutApp As Object

Dim OutMail As Object

Dim cell As Range

Dim FileCell As Range

Dim rng As Range

With Application

.EnableEvents = False

.ScreenUpdating = False

End With

Set rng = Nothing

On Error Resume Next

Set rng = Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

On Error GoTo 0

If rng Is Nothing Then

MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _

vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly

Exit Sub

End If

With Application

.EnableEvents = False

End With

For Each cell In rng

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With OutMail

.To = cell.Value

.Subject = "test mail"
```